# Magento 2 is sending order confirmation email when order is voided in Braintree and not created in Magento backend

Tags: magento2, order-email, voiding

I'm at a lost - orders are reporting that they received an order confirmation email (which I can see in our logs are being sent) but the orders are not actually created in our system.

When I search via the admin order grid - the order is not there.

When I search Braintree, I can see the order number and that the transaction has been voided.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check for clues in your log files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Plugin/AccessChangeQuoteControl.php::beforeSave()` - this triggers `isAllowed()`. If `false`, then an exception is thrown.

This was only returning false during after payment authorization and as Magento attempted to modify the cart quote.

`isAllowed()` tests:
    - (a) Is customer logged in && does customer ID match quote ID. If this fails, the exception is thrown. I think this is our issue since this only happens to registered users. It could be a migration issue on customer quotes.
   - (b) it tests "if guest", a logged in customer is not allowed.
   - (c) and, if admin, `true` always

If any other code happens to throw an exception during this request, you'll end up with the same problem.